# How to get last object in json array and insert to new array

Tags: arrays, json, flutter

I'm developing a flutter app and I have JSON array it comes from API and it's include object in list array so I need to get the last object in an array and push the last object to new array Because I need return that array list into list view for showing ... How can I do this

**My code**

```dart
main() {
  var  data = json.decode('[ {"id":42,"image_path":"https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1583971227.jpg","hall_details":"*********"},
    {"id":52,"image_path":"https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1584390666.jpg",
    "hall_details":" Could anyone please help me with this. I am stuck here. Have been trying different methods but none working. Thank you"},
    {"id":62,
    "image_path":"https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1584453580.jpg",
    "hall_details":"Could anyone please help me with this. I am stuck here. Have been trying different methods but none working. Thank you."},
    {"id":65,
    "image_path":"https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1584453580.jpg",
    "hall_details":"Could anyone please help me with this. I am stuck here. Have been trying different methods but none working. Thank you."}]');

  Map responseJson = data[data.length-1];
      
  List returnMovies = [];
     
  returnMovies.addAll({responseJson});
            
  print(returnMovies);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic answer is to use this library https://github.com/k-paxian/dart-json-mapper,

It will help you not only for this case, but for all Dart Object => JSON => Dart Object cases.

Please carefully read library readme document first, especially section "Basic setup".

Code below will help you to grasp main Idea:

```dart
import 'main.reflectable.dart' show initializeReflectable;
import 'package:dart_json_mapper/dart_json_mapper.dart' show jsonSerializable, JsonMapperAdapter, typeOf, JsonMapper, DeserializationOptions, CaseStyle;

@jsonSerializable
class Movie {
  int id;
  String imagePath;
  String hallDetails;
}

void main {
      initializeReflectable();

      // given
      final json =
          '''[{"id":42,"image_path":"https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1583971227.jpg","hall_details":"*********"},
      {"id":52,"image_path":"https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1584390666.jpg",
      "hall_details":" Could anyone please help me with this. I am stuck here. Have been trying different methods but none working. Thank you"},
      {"id":62,
      "image_path":"https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1584453580.jpg",
      "hall_details":"Could anyone please help me with this. I am stuck here. Have been trying different methods but none working. Thank you."},
      {"id":65,
      "image_path":"https://fathomless-brushlands-95996.herokuapp.com/Imaga_halls/1584453580.jpg",
      "hall_details":"Could anyone please help me with this. I am stuck here. Have been trying different methods but none working. Thank you."}]''';

      JsonMapper().useAdapter(JsonMapperAdapter(valueDecorators: {
        typeOf<List<Movie>>(): (value) => value.cast<Movie>()
      }));

      // when
      final moviesList = JsonMapper.deserialize<List<Movie>>(
          json, DeserializationOptions(caseStyle: CaseStyle.Snake));

      // then
      expect(moviesList.last, TypeMatcher<Movie>());

      print(moviesList.last.id);
      print(moviesList.last.hallDetails);
      print(moviesList.last.imagePath);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot bro